# Synced multithreading add 1 to number, varying results

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't know if this is working the right way, but I'm attempting to add 1 to a variable using 1000 threads. I then print out the number at the end to verify that it worked, it never is 1000 and it also changes.

I determined this is likely a synchronization issue from googling and look on SO but when I try to sync the threads, it still isn't 1000 at the end and varies but a lot less (varies between 995 to 997 whereas without sync it varies between 900 and 1000 roughly).

Here is what I'm doing so far:

```
public class Main extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[1000];

        Adder adder = new Adder();

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadAddSync(adder));
            threads[i].start();

        }

        System.out.println("----- " + adder.count);
    }
}

public class ThreadAddSync implements Runnable{

    Adder add;

    public ThreadAddSync(Adder add){
        this.add = add;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(add){
            add.add();
        }
    }
}

public class Adder {

    int count = 0;

    public void add(){
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

My question is should these threads be synced the way I have this written? And if they are synced why are they producing varying results if they're technically safe?

Comment: You don't wait for the threads to complete, so you're printing the result before the work is done. You need a second loop calling [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) on each thread.

Comment: @Andreas, okay, I did that before but inside the loop where I start the thread so I was doing start then immediately join which I think means it wouldn't start the next thread until the previous one had finished negating the point of threads. But if I do it after the loop where I start them then...I see how that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println("----- " + adder.count);` - you access `count` but don't `synchronize` on `adder` and thus, it is **not safe** (nor did you wait for the workers to complete, `join()` if you expect to see the final total before you print the total, or add another loop to wait). Also, in real code, you ***should*** be using [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: Even with `synchronized`, the result may be wrong, because OP never wait for threads to complete, so may be printing result too early.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I assumed OP had some mechanism is the main thread to watch the total and was seeing the totals jump (varying results). If it's literally as posted then I agree with you.

Comment: Okay, so that worked, now it shows 1000 every time, but when I remove the synchronize so it's running unsafely, it also still gets to 1000. Does that make sense? I thought it would write the same number occasionally and the count wouldn't get up to 1000?

Comment: @Redcoatwright Your threads are very short-lived, so probability of clash is very small. Try calling `add.add()` many times (1000+) in a loop in the `run` method.

Comment: @Redcoatwright Also, it takes time to start a thread, so create two [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), one with a count of 1000 and one with a count of 1. Have the threads `countDown()` the large one then `await()` on the small one before entering above loop. In the main thread, between the `start()` and `join()` loops, `await()` on the large one then `countDown()` the small one. This will ensure that the overhead of starting threads is complete before the threads begin their job.